# Can I iterate dynamic array without knowing the size of it

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I allocated some data in a dynamic array of a `struct`. Can I iterate that `struct *` without knowing it's size somehow?

Would this work?

```
int main() {
    struct *foo = NULL;

    //struct filling

    iterate_foo(foo);
}

void iterate_foo(struct *foo) {
    int i=0;
 
    while (foo[i] != NULL) {    // Would this work?

        //something
    }
}
```

Comment: No.  It really is that simple - because you can't iterate **anything** without knowing the size.  In any language.  Other languages may track the size of an array for you, but C doesn't do that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that can work is if you have a sentinel value in the array that indicates the end. Strings in C work that way.

For instance, if you invoke `strcpy(a, b)`, then characters from `b` will be copied to `a` until and including the value zero. If there's no zero terminator within the `b` array, or if `a` is not big enough to hold all the characters, the function call leads to undefined behavior.

If you don't want to use a sentinel value, you have the option of passing the size as a separate parameter. Another way is to wrap things in a container struct, like this:

```
struct container {
    struct mystruct *data;
    size_t size;
}
```

Furthermore, `struct *foo = NULL;` is wrong. It has to be something like `struct mystruct *foo = NULL;`

But if you have this code:

```
void foo(T *ptr) {
    // Do something
}

int main(void) {
    T *a = malloc(N * sizeof *a);
    T b[N];
    foo(a);
    foo(b);
}
```

Then it's completely impossible for `foo` to figure out `N` in a portable way. In some cases, believe that the implementation of `malloc` stores the size right before the data. But don't try to exploit that. It will only cause severe head ache.

Comment: ... or a length stored separately

Comment: @eewanco Yes, but op specifically said that the length should not be stored separately.